# group_concat in subquery

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tbl1.logid)  ,
(

    SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT tbl2.client_id ) 
    FROM tbl_client tbl2

    WHERE tbl2.con_id
    IN ( GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tbl1.logid) ) 


) as PC2,

from tbl_table tbl1;
```

i try to assign an alias of GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tbl1.logid) and place it in the value inside the IN() but still it doesn't work out

the parent query returns something like 12,34,3,56
and that i want to use in the IN function

this not actually the whole case, but i just want to figure this out,

Comment: I removed tags `oop`, `class` and `eval` because they did not seem to apply.  If I am wrong, please explain.  And I added `sql`.

Comment: group concat is returning a string. Use the result set inside IN()

Comment: ah yes,sorry i forgot to change it thanks by the way ..  ;)

Comment: Is it your intention to only return a single row result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the output of [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for IN() as it is returning a string. Use the result of a subquery for IN().

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tbl1.logid)  ,
(

SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT tbl2.client_id ) 
FROM tbl_client tbl2

WHERE tbl2.con_id
IN ( SELECT logid from tbl_table ) 


) 

as PC2,

from tbl_table tbl1;
```