# Condition check with IN clause mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a string returned from a function "'aa','bb','cc',..."(the function uses GROUP_CONCAT). I want to use this as a condition in the IN clase of mysql.

```
SELECT name,class,comment
FROM vwstudent v
WHERE name IN (select func())
```

I want the query to act like

```
SELECT name,class,comment
FROM vwstudent v
WHERE name IN ('aa','bb','cc','dd',..)
```

I assume ('aa','bb','cc','dd',..) is acting as a whole string here and isn't generating any result. What can I do to run this query error less.

Comment: The string is generated by `GROUP_CONCAT()`?  Then you should probably be joining the tables and forgetting about `GROUP_CONCAT()` and `IN()`.  Classic [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19465469/575376

Comment: Or see this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11425315/149076

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it'll help.  But you might be able to hack something together by using PREPARE and EXECUTE as described here: [How To have Dynamic SQL in MySQL Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure)

... but that's completely new to me.  I've never used anything like that in MySQL.